# Indexing a vector of vectors

Tags: vector, rust

Hello I am trying to create a 2D vector in rust simply by making a vector of vectors and then printing it in a 2D form.

Code:

```
fn draw_grid(grid:&Vec<Vec<i32>>){

for r in 0..grid.len(){
    for c in 0..grid.len(){
        print!("{}", grid[r[c]]);
    }
}
```

error:

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `usize`
```

As you can see the compiler doesn't like it when I try to index it like a normal vector. Your help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't indexing a vector, you are indexing an integer.

```rust
for r in 0..grid.len() {
    // r is an integer here
    for c in 0..grid.len() {
        // yet you are trying to index it as if it were an array: r[c]
        print!("{}", grid[r[c]]);
    }
}
```

The simple fix is to do `print!("{}", grid[r][c]);`.

However, the idiomatic way to iterate a vector in Rust is this:

```rust
for r in grid {
    for c in r {
        print!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, with the `flatten` method that's defined for iterators on things that can be turned into iterators: `for element in grid.iter().flatten()`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `grid[r][c]`.

- `grid` is your vector of vector.
- `grid[r]` is the r-th row, which is itself a vector.
- `grid[r][c]`, which can be seen as `(grid[r])[c]` if that helps, is element on the c-th column of that row.